# Maven: Need a way to change a property or URL value if the project is being released or not

Tags: java, maven, nexus

We're using the JDeb maven plugin to build debian packages of our one-jar'd projects.

We have two APT repositories, one for pre-release builds, and one for releases.

We're using the Wagon plugin to upload the artifacts, but we cannot figure out how to only send releases to the release repository, and snapshots to the pre-release repo.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>upload-to-nexus</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>upload-single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>xxx-all</serverId>
                <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${jdeb.name}</fromFile>
                <url>https://xxx.xxx.xxx/repository/xxx-apt-pre</url>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

We need to change `xxx-apt-pre` above to `xxx-apt-dist` when the release plugin runs. For the life of me, I cannot figure out a way to do this.

I initially tried using the build-helper plugin to regex the `${project.build.finalName}` for the phrase `SNAPSHOT`, but it won't overwrite the existing property.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Use a system environment property, or a command line parameter during build.

Comment: It needs to be automatic so our CI system can deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution wasn't pretty, but gets 'er done as we say in the midwest:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-dynamic-properties</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                <![CDATA[
                    if (project.version.contains('SNAPSHOT')) {
                        project.properties['aptRepoName'] = 'xxx-apt-pre'
                    } else {
                        project.properties['aptRepoName'] = 'xxx-apt-dist'
                    }
                ]]>
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>upload-to-nexus</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>upload-single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>xxx-all</serverId>
                <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${jdeb.name}</fromFile>
                <url>https://xxx.xxx.xxx/repository/${aptRepoName}</url>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I hope this helps someone or someday someone posts a better way.